# Cloud SQL with Firebase Functions V2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

I'm receiving `connect ENOENT /cloudsql/<proj>:us-west1:<instance>/.s.PGSQL.5432` When connecting to a Cloud SQL instance of PostgreSQL 15 from a **Firebase** V2 Callable function. I've looked everywhere and even reluctantly used ChatGPT but I cannot seem to fix the issue.

1. I have checked my connection config (with the values substituted out)

```
export const createUnixSocketPool = (config: DatabaseConfig) => {
  return knex({
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      database: "default",
      host: "/cloudsql/<proj-id>:us-west1:<instance-name>",
    },
    pool: { min: 0, max: 1 },
  });
};
```

2. project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com has the appropriate Client role for Cloud SQL.
3. Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code configuration looks good, but the service configuration is not. You must tell to the service to open a connection with your Cloud SQL database, and then to open a unix socket for your code

I didn't find anywhere how to set up a Cloud SQL connection for Firebase Functions V2. The most appropriate documentation page is on [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#configure).

Comment: Didn't see this. Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to deploy cfs with this flag? The --add-cloudsql-instances unsurprisingly doesn't work.

Comment: No, it's not possible with flags for now. In addition, there will be an evolution in the strategy that will be announced at Cloud Next. In short, focus on Cloud Run!