# Google Cloud Run Assign Cloud SQL Connection Issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-artifact-registry

When creating a new revision to my cloud run instance to add a Cloud SQL connection I receive the error: `Revision '<name>-00005-w5r' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Image 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/<project>/gcf-artifacts/<image-name>' not found.` (redacted). Even when I explicitly check that the image url is the exact same as a previously deployed image.

The original image of previous instances is built buy Firebase Functions V2. This method was found on [The Google Cloud Docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) for accessing Cloud SQL from cloud functions.

I don't understand how the image could be deleted since the cloud functions need it to re-run in case of completion or restart so far as I'm aware.

Same goes for when I use `gcloud run services update<name> --add-cloudsql-instances=<project>:us-west1:<instance>` I get the same error.

---

Follow up of [Cloud SQL with Firebase Functions V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78117604/cloud-sql-with-firebase-functions-v2)

Comment: Did you delete some buckets in your project?

Comment: Just in case, what happens if you try to pull the image? Does it work or not?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I haven't deleted any buckets, no.

Comment: @MrThompson, It gives me a resource not found error. Which checks out, however, I have never touched artefact registry. It also gives me a resource not found if I directly follow the link on the first revision of the cloud run instance, which is running and healthy.

Comment: I have no idea how the build cycle works for cfs. Could it be that when a cf is deployed and restarted it builds the image from cache (which is present in the gc artifacts repo) and the image link that cloud run has is just the build destination that is present after the build? Then the cycle deletes the built image after it is mounted in the cloud run instance. When I create the revision the build cycle isn't triggered, thus the link is dead?

Comment: What happens if you try to deploy the hello world for Cloud Run?